# How do I change the characteristics of a dojo currency text box in xpages?

Tags: css, dojo, xpages

I have seen some threads attempting to answer, but I don't see a definite solution, at least one that I can understand how to implement.

Is there a way to easily change the  css of a dojo field in XPages? In this case I am a Dojo Currency Text Box.

```
<xe:djCurrencyTextBox id="I_H2"
                        value="#{document1.I_H2}" style="width:60px;">
        <xe:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber type="currency"></xp:convertNumber>
        </xe:this.converter>                
</xe:djCurrencyTextBox>
```

I've read how you can't apply styles directly to it because it's being controlled by a theme and it's wrapped in other div and span tags (although it accepts width), but surely there must a be simple way to adjust the field's background color and other characteristics?

Comment: Like any other design element, you should be able to assign a StyleClass, which in HTML is a "class".  You can then have a custom CSS file and overwrite the applied style to that class. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Steve, If I apply a StyleClass to this dojo field element, it does not work as it does with every other field and a lot of other elements for which I've applied a css class. e.g.  styleClass="cashBox". As the page loads, you can actually see the styleClass being applied to that text box and then disappear as if it is being overwritten by a theme applied to dojo elementss

Comment: When you say it doesn't work. Do you mean that the class doesn't get applied, or that *your* style changes are not showing up even with the class there. If the latter, I have an answer for you. (I see your edited comment, answer pending)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue in XPages before. To prevent your styles from being overwritten add "`!important`" after them. Note that CSS purists frown on this approach, but it does work.

I have not had much success with disabling a theme, but you can try that if you haven't already.

This blog post I wrote, explains more about the use of "`!important`" and I think will help you: http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2014/10/quick-tip-forcing-css-override.html

Comment: It's not working. My class looks like yours .cashBox {
 color:#222 !important;
  }     and the class is applied to the element correctly <xe:djCurrencyTextBox id="I_H2"
       value="#{document1.I_H2}" style="width:60px;" styleClass="cashBox">   I don't think this works with dojo form fields...or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is your styling loaded in a custom CSS file loaded as a resource on that page?

Comment: <xp:styleSheet href="/shipments.css"></xp:styleSheet>   yes, the style sheet is a resource on the page and all the other classes are applied and working. the only class not working is the one applied to the dojo fields.

Comment: Sound like you are doing everything right. Next, I would use Chrome tools to play around with the styles real time. I would expect to see your color class with strikethrough, meaning that it is being overwritten. If not, and the style is not applied, then I would conclude you can't change it. If it is overwritten, then figure out how, and see if you can manipulate it.

Comment: If anyone can, please show me an example of this working on a dojo field.